# Cassandra multi-dimensional datamodel

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cql

I'm new to Cassandra data modelling and I have a scenario where I need to accommodate *multi-dimensional* data in a single row if possible(yes I knew Cassandra is columnar storage).My sample dataset (Tried to simplify my use case, bear with my formating )

> timestamp, transaction_id, item_code, user_id, payment_method
>
> 20130304221518, abcd, 3, 6, creditcard
>
> 20130304221519, efgh, 4, 5, cashondelivery
>
> 20130305180402, ijkl, 4, 5, cashondelivery

For instance, `payment_mode,user_id,item_code` are my dimentions and I want to aggregate the dataset with given dimensions.My simple aggregated result would be

```
payment_method = {cashondelivery = 2, credit card = 1)
Transaction_by_unique_user_id ={5 =2,6=1}
item_code = {item sold =3, Unique_item_sold (4 =2 ,3=1) }
```

Note that in near future, I may need to add some more dimensions and the data model should accommodate those as well.I want to model it in Cassandra way and I have following approaches in front of me.

1. New table for every dimension.
2. Add dimensions as new columns and use `map` as data type. 
   If you notice one of my result `item_code = {item sold =3, Unique_item_sold (4 =2 ,3=1) }`, This sort of result cannot be accommodated with `map` data type and dimension as column name.
3. Insert each dimension value as new row in single table.

Also note that ,I would be reading the data very often.So read should not be performance hit to my data model. *My aggregation will happen every 1 hour of data and I use Spark for analytics *.Kindly suggest me the right approach.Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to aggregate all the data or specific day, month or year ?

Comment: Basically , aggregation will happen minute to hours dataset.

Comment: Is your aggregation result only the count (cashondelivery = 2) or list of transaction id ?

Comment: Mostly yes.....

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have to insert huge data regularly. So we have to choose the partition key carefully, so that huge data not inserted into a single partition. Though you are aggregating result every hour, i choose the partition as hourly interval.

Here is the main table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
    hour int,
    day int,
    month int,
    year int,
    transaction_id text,
    item_code bigint,
    payment_method text,
    user_id bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY ((hour, day, month, year), transaction_id)
);
```

Here you can speparate the timestamp field into hour day month and year.

If you want to aggregate the result you should use Spark or Hadoop, is best choice for this kinds of job.

or

If you want to do this kinds of job in cassandra, you have to use separate table for each dimension. When you are inserting data on main table,also have to insert data on each table.

Aggregate payment_method :

```
CREATE TABLE payment_method_counter (
    hour int,
    day int,
    month int,
    year int,
    type text,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((hour, day, month, year), type)
);
```

You can insert data with the below query :

```
UPDATE payment_method_counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE hour = 1 AND day = 1 AND month = 1 AND year = 2017 AND type = 'cashondelivery';
```

Aggregate Transaction_by_unique_user_id :

```
CREATE TABLE user_transaction_counter (
    hour int,
    day int,
    month int,
    year int,
    userid bigint,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((hour, day, month, year), userid)
);
```

And insert query :

```
UPDATE user_transaction_counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE hour = 1 AND day = 1 AND month = 1 AND year = 2017 AND userid = 5;
```

Aggregate item sold :

```
CREATE TABLE item_sold_counter (
    hour int,
    day int,
    month int,
    year int,
    item_code bigint,
    count counter,
    PRIMARY KEY ((hour, day, month, year), item_code)
);
```

And you can query :

```
UPDATE item_sold_counter SET count = count + 1 WHERE hour = 1 AND day = 1 AND month = 1 AND year = 2017 AND item_code = 4;
```

Here for total item sold use a special value like `item_code = 0`. for each item sold also insert a value with `item_code = 0`

Getting Result :

You can get aggregation result for an hour like these below query :

```
cassandra@cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM payment_method_counter  WHERE hour = 1 AND day = 1 AND month = 1 AND year = 2017;

 hour | day | month | year | type           | count
------+-----+-------+------+----------------+-------
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 | cashondelivery |     2
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 |     creditcard |     1

(2 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM user_transaction_counter WHERE hour = 1 AND day = 1 AND month = 1 AND year = 2017;

 hour | day | month | year | userid | count
------+-----+-------+------+--------+-------
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 |      5 |     2
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 |      6 |     1

(2 rows)
cassandra@cqlsh:test> SELECT * FROM item_sold_counter  WHERE hour = 1 AND day = 1 AND month = 1 AND year = 2017;

 hour | day | month | year | item_code | count
------+-----+-------+------+-----------+-------
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 |         0 |     3
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 |         3 |     1
    1 |   1 |     1 | 2017 |         4 |     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and research into the scenario. will try this and get back to you.

Comment: you suggesting to have different table for every dimension  here?

Comment: Yes my data volume is substantial and i'm using spark for processing

Comment: @BalajiReddy spark is best suited for your use case.

Comment: @ Ashraful Islam yes